# File drag and drop test case in React using RTL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've created file upload functionality using React DnD, while creating test case for the component i'm getting error - Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Cannot call hover while not dragging.]
Does anybody knows how to solve this issue ? here is my example sandbox - [FileDragAndDrop](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mestorf-1ypx2d?file=/src/__test__/Test.test.tsx)